# C pointer to 2D arrays

Tags: c, pointers, implicit-conversion

Throughout my c codes. ignore confusing identifier name.  Reason what in assignment of ptr61 pointer i have to put address (&) operator, while & is needless in assignment of ptr62 pointer.

```
int var6[3][4] = {
    {1,2,3,4},
    {5,6,7,8},
    {9,10,11,12}
};

int (*ptr61)[][4];
ptr61 = &var6;
printf("lvl 9: %d\n", (*ptr61)[2][0]);

int (*ptr62)[4];
ptr62 = var6;
printf("lvl 9: %d\n",*(*(ptr62 + 1)+2));
```

Comment: @VladfromMoscow thanks for ur feedback. difference between ptr61 = &var6 and ptr62 = var6, why error happen if i put ptr62 = &var6 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An array designator used in expressions like for example as initializer is implicitly converted to pointer to its first element.

So if you have an array like this

```
int var6[3][4] = {
    {1,2,3,4},
    {5,6,7,8},
    {9,10,11,12}
};
```

then this declaration declares an array of 3 elements of the type `int[4]`. Thus pointer to element of the array will have the type `int ( * )[4]` and you may write

```
int (*ptr62)[4] = var6;
```

If you will write

```
ptr62 = &var6;
```

you will get a compiler error because in the left side hand of the assignment there is an object of the type `int( * )[4]` while in the right hand side there is an object of the type `int( * )[3][4]` and these types are not compatible and there is no implicit conversion from one type to another.

If you want to declare a pointer to the whole array that has the type `int[3][4]` then such a pointer will have the type `int ( * )[3][4]` and you may  write

```
int (*ptr61)[3][4] = &var6;
```

As for this declaration

```
int (*ptr61)[][4] = &var6;
```

then it declares a pointer to the incomplete array type `int[][4]`.